# Enable word wrap in JupyterLab code editor

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I would like to enable word wrap for the code cells in jupyterlab, but do not manage to find how.

Already tried:

- File --> Settings --> Text Editor --> User Overrides:`{"lineWrap": true}`, which toggles the greyed-out "word wrap" in the "Editor" menu, but does not solve my problem
- This code also did not work (neither did simply "Cell": {...} ):

> ```
> "CodeCell": {
>     "cm_config": {
>       "lineWrapping": true
>     }
>   }
> ```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try the following,

```
{
   "codeCellConfig": {
      "lineWrap": "wordWrapColumn",
      "wordWrapColumn": 80
   }
}
```

For reference, see this [pull request from the JupyterLap project on GitHub](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/pull/4936).

Comment: I guess this was implemented since January. Just `"lineWrap": "on"` did the trick for me, but generally your answer is correct. Thank you for the reminder.

Comment: Any chance that you know how to enable text wrapping on google colaboratory jupyter notebook? I have updated to the latest notebook: (5.7.8) but no text wrap option on text output is available on colaboratory.

Comment: Sorry, but I can't help you there.

Comment: [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58768173/how-to-wrap-code-in-cells-on-jupyterlab-version-1-1-4) helped me to figure out where to put the settings.

Answer (score 8):

Here is how I solved it :

Settings -> Advanced Settings Editor -> Notebook
to  user preferences add

```
{"codeCellConfig": {
        
        "lineWrap": "on",
        
    },}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Working as of 1 May 2022 for JupyterLab v3.2.1**

I feel that the answer above is not clear enough, and hope to provide a quick solution for those who visit this page in the future.

How to enable word wrap in JupyterLab

1. Click on Settings > Advanced Settings Editor > Select Notebook (at the sidebar)
2. On the `User Preferences` tab, enter the following to enable word wrap

```
{
    "codeCellConfig":{
         "lineWrap": "on"
    }
}
```

#### Before

[image]

#### After

[image]