# How to set word wrap & code folding in Jupyterlab by editing User Settings File/User Preferences File

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I have two sub-questions of the question shown in title:

1. **Where does JupyterLab store `System Defaults` and `User Preference` files?**

   - Which are displayed in the GUI's Advanced Settings Edit page/Notebook as show in bellow picture.
   - [image]
   - The most similar file I can find is `/usr/local/share/jupyter/lab/schemas/@jupyterlab/notebook-extension/tracker.json`, **but I'm not sure if this file is for `System Defaults` or `User Preference` or neither**
2. I want to customized my own JupyterLab settings by editing the config file, and there are several **file path** suggestion I found in websites:

   1. `/usr/local/share/jupyter/lab/settings/overrides.json`
   2. `~/.jupyter/lab/user-settings/@jupyterlab/notebook-extension/tracker.jupyterlab-settings`
   3. `/usr/local/share/jupyter/lab/schemas/@jupyterlab/notebook-extension/tracker.json`

   - My question is: **Which correct file should I edit if I want to adjust settings like
     *code folding*, *line wrapping*?  Or none of above, there is other file I should use?**

PS. Because I start JupyterLab in a docker container, and I rebuild the container frequently, I want to change the default settings by editing the config file instead of changing these settings in the GUI every time.

Thank you all.

ref:

- [JupyterLab User Settings File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48950670/jupyterlab-user-settings-file)
- [Enable word wrap in JupyterLab code editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48202340/enable-word-wrap-in-jupyterlab-code-editor)
- https://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user/directories.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *codeFolding* & *wordWarping* settings are related to the jupyterlab `extension`—`@jupyterlab/notebook-extension` and the `plugin`—`tracker`.

There are two Jupyter Lab User Setting files you can edit to adjust codeFolding setting.

So there are two options, you can choose  one of them:

- file 1: `~/.jupyter/lab/user-settings/@jupyterlab/notebook-extension/tracker.jupyterlab-settings`

  According to the [documents of jupyter lab](https://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user/directories.html#jupyterlab-user-settings-directory):

  > By default, the location is `$HOME/.jupyter/lab/user-settings/`, where
  > `$HOME` is the user’s home directory. This folder is not in the
  > JupyterLab application directory because these settings are typically
  > shared across Python environments. The location can be modified using
  > the `JUPYTERLAB_SETTINGS_DIR environment` variable.

  > JSON5 files are automatically created in this folder recording the
  > settings changes a user makes in the JupyterLab Advanced Settings
  > Editor. The file names follow the pattern of
  > `<extension_name>/<plugin_name>.jupyterlab-settings`.

  So we should edit `~/.jupyter/lab/user-settings/@jupyterlab/notebook-extension/tracker.jupyterlab-settings`.

  Any settings you write in this file, would override the default settings
- file 2: `/usr/local/share/jupyter/lab/schemas/@jupyterlab/notebook-extension/tracker.json`
  We can also edit `/usr/local/share/jupyter/lab/schemas/@jupyterlab/notebook-extension/tracker.json`.

  But by editing this file, you are change default settings directly.