Automatic line warp does not work for code cell in Jupyter Lab 4.2.0
I want to automatically wrap my code cell in Jupyter lab at 80 character. In Advanced Settings Editor, for the following block:
"codeCellConfig": {
    "autoClosingBrackets": [80],
    "lineWrap": true,
    "rulers": [
        80
    ]
},

I tried "lineWrap": true,, "lineWrap": "on",, and this:
"lineWrap": "wordWrapColumn",
"wordWrapColumn": 80,

I also tried [80] in place of 80. None worked.
I am working inside "codeCellConfig", but I do not know why I cannot anyhow enable line warpping in code cell.

rulers is just to display visual guide ruler at 80 characters, not to modify wrapping. It looks like lineWrap in CodeMirror is not configurable - it just uses the width of editor to determine when to wrap. Someone would need to create a CodeMirror6 extension which supports wrapping at pre-specified number of characters

Possibly relevant discussion on why implementing this is hard: https://discuss.codemirror.net/t/editor-driven-line-wrapping/5125

I do see examples of success on StackOverflow https://stackoverflow.com/a/72074068/4923935, but I didn't.

The post you linked refers to JupyterLab 3.x which used CodeMirror 5 but JupyterLab 4.x uses CodeMirror 6.

It seems my code cell does not even use the width of the editor. I never gets wrapped to the second line. In Markdown cell, the width of the editor determines when to wrap. Any idea how to at least enable wrapping at editor width in code cell?

There is no magic hidden options that JupyterLab maintainers try to hide away from users. If it does not work, it is a bug and please report it in JupyterLab repo ;)
